# Python api for every type

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way/IDE to make python show the api for every type? (int, file etc...) just like in Eclipse for java where you write varname. and it shows you all the possible functions for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is duck-typed so you will never get the exact API for each variable that you can get from a strongly-typed (if you excuse me for using "strong-typed" as the opposite of "duck-typed") language such as Java.

However, most IDEs such as PyCharm and Eclipse PyDev do offer intelligent auto-completion that you would expect from a proper IDE.